# Java JDBC | Cannot run from console

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar, console

I have developed a program where I do some database connections and send some queries with JDBC.

I have used MySQL, NetBeans 6.9 under Ubuntu 11.04 as platform. When I run the app from NetBeans, it works perfectly but when I try to run it from terminal I get SQL Exception. This is the function that produces that SQL Exception. The program terminates before "Establish is ending" line.

```
public Connection Establish(String iname, String ipassword) throws SQLException
{
    System.out.println("Establish...");
    if(conn == null)
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ANU",
                iname, ipassword);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Connection Already Established!");
    System.out.println("Establish is ending...");
    return conn;
} // End of Establish
```

Comment: 1. Is this a JDBC driver? If so you have to instantiate the JDBC driver first
2. What is the STACKTRACE?

Comment: Copy & paste the exact text of the exception. The more detailed information you give, the better we can help you.

Comment: @MJB: with Java6 and a JDBC4 (3?) compliant driver it's no longer necessary to instantiate the driver as it will (should) register itself with the DriverManager automatically

Comment: horse - Yes, I am well aware. but for all we know Mert is running Java 1.2 :) . In fact my original post to say JDBC3 in original question - it flows better too.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the MySQL Connector .jar file is in your classpath environment variable. IDEs, like NetBeans, sometimes help you out with putting .jar files in the classpath while you're in the IDE. You'll either need to run your app with the -cp  option, or add it to your classpath environment variable.